# something is "blocking" my images from loading faster tried apache configs, nginx, cache header stuff, nothing changes

Tags: apache-2.4, cache, website, network-speed

**THE ISSUE** : the images in my site takes a bit to start loading... like if something is blocking, but ***unable to pinpoint what*** could be the cause.

PHP 8 / latest WHM

LIVE EXAMPLE : https://www.stubfeed.com/crypto

WHAT I TRYED [.0A.] : changing web hosting company => no change, there is something in my web code...

WHAT I TRYED [.0B.] : I was with centos 7 and changed to centos 8 => still the same

WHAT I TRYED [.0C.] : Disabling php-fpm => it helped a lot, but still the wait for images is there.

WHAT I TRYED [.0D.] : ouput buffers on or off => still the same

WHAT I TRYED [.1.] : merge all my .css and .js in fewer files ( 2.css 2.js instead of multiple) // also added font-display:swap;

WHAT I TRYED [.2.] : nginx reverse proxy for apache (on or off => no change since cloudflare acts as a CDN...)

WHAT I TRYED [3] : apache configs

```
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header always set Referrer-Policy "no-referrer"
Header always set Permissions-Policy "geolocation=(self),midi=(self),sync-xhr=(self),magnetometer=(self),gyroscope=(self),fullscreen=(self)"
```

WHAT I TRYED [4] : .htaccess cache control headers

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    <FilesMatch “\.(webp|webm|flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|mp4|m4v|m4a|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|apng|swf|css|js|otf|ttf|woff)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

WHAT I TRYED [5] : convert *ALL* my images in webp -quality 60 (with iMageMagick) => it reduced the size a lot ;) ==>> but still didn't fixed the issue.

WHAT I TRIED [6] : in google chrome console => "empty cache hard reload" => seems faster to normal load ???

WHAT I TRIED [7] : in google chrome console => network tab => I see loaded from cache but somehow with my eyes, I see the menu very fast but all other images, it waits for 1 or 2 seconds before showing up

WHAT I TRIED [8] : add a page rule in cloudflare https://www.stubfeed.com/media/*
Browser Cache TTL: a year, Cache Level: Cache Everything, Edge Cache TTL: 14 days, Cache Deception Armor: On, Origin Cache Control: On

WHAT I TRIED [9] : Load 4, 6, 9, 23 images => al the same, still : what I see with my eyes (wait 1 sec, then images appears....) [the speed testers says ...]

WHAT I TRIED [10] : service worker with caching all fecth... => I turned it off because checking from cache before was terribly slower... :( you can see it there : https://www.stubfeed.com/ws.js?v=202108000021 (in cachable array I added wepb, but I removed it...)

THE RESULT WITH ALL THOSE TRIES : the menu, the .css, the .js ==>> very fast and instantaneous... but still images after 1 (some times 2) seconds...

you can see a report here : https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.stubfeed.com/4MGVqAFv/

[image]
[image]

```
curl -I https://www.stubfeed.com/media/feed/2021/08/02/14463960829226.webp

HTTP/2 200 
date: Mon, 02 Aug 2021 02:13:44 GMT
content-type: image/webp
content-length: 78296
x-content-type-options: nosniff
referrer-policy: no-referrer
permissions-policy: geolocation=(self),midi=(self),sync-xhr=(self),magnetometer=(self),gyroscope=(self),fullscreen=(self)
last-modified: Mon, 02 Aug 2021 01:40:11 GMT
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload
cache-control: public, max-age=31536000
cf-cache-status: HIT
age: 1483
accept-ranges: bytes
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=QawI6BH%2FlcrvvsUxJ6VgTJzwNqvb%2BVqBRo1gbxng6JRggJe9MgZbkWhLtMjmwvwC8yB3SLaoJXT%2BvNZDuLCzya1g8HlxGFbpFMzXB%2F4p%2B9GcIGIZANk%2FjfvIx0Lu2t07QIsr"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
nel: {"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 6783c9ea7f3c4bd1-YUL
alt-svc: h3-27=":443"; ma=86400, h3-28=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400, h3=":443"; ma=86400
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.stubfeed.com%2F crypto says a 95 scale which is great?

Comment: @djdomi nice ;) but how can this be different when you do it from your end vs doing the same from my end with different result ? also, by checking the tries I made, do you know if something could be improved ?

Comment: my internet has 1gbit, hows about yours? :P

Comment: @djdomi 77 Mbps

Comment: @djdomi turns out it was many factors, 1 => my images are in filebase.com (nice decentralized object storage solution) was not the issue 2 => my internet provider has a buffer or TTL (or not sure the right term to use) very high and during high loads, the filebase.com load balancers kicks in and provide new ips.... my internet provider points to old ip during that load balancing thing.... 3 => see my answer I was waiting for the page load to do a ajax call (that was the blocker)... I'm using php so I did include instead of ajax call...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After deeper digging I found it.

It was the "steps" I had... load page then ajax...

I rethinked and did an include.

I also reshaped my ajax to be async await

```
    async function stubajax (divid,phphat,postix = [],pend = 'html') {
    
        var pcache = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000) + 1);
        
        postix["preventcache"] = pcache;
        postix["divid"] = encodeURIComponent(divid);
        postix["mojax_height"] = encodeURIComponent($(window).height());
        postix["mojax_width"] = encodeURIComponent($(window).width());

postix["cookies"] = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie); // if you need to send cookies
        
        for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){ postix[localStorage.key(i)] = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)); }
        for (var i = 0; i < sessionStorage.length; i++){ postix[sessionStorage.key(i)] = sessionStorage.getItem(sessionStorage.key(i)); }
            
        await fetch(phphat+"?pcache="+pcache+"&fetchx="+pcache, {
          method: "POST", body: JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, postix)), headers: {"Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}
        }).then( response => { return response.text(); }).then( html => { 
            switch ( pend ){
                case 'append' : $("#"+divid+"_message").append(extraforml+html); break;
                case 'prepend' : $("#"+divid+"_message").prepend(extraforml+html); break;
                default : $("#"+divid+"_message").html(extraforml+html); break;
            }
        }).catch( err => console.log(err) );
          
    }
```

can later be called like this

```
stubajax('id','...php',{'somevar1':'hello'});
```

// (when 100% on each topics is reached on light house, they added a fireworks animation)

[image]